# Using glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex()

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I am facing some doubt while using glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex().

Following is the source code :

```
GLfloat vertices[]=
    {
        -0.9,-0.9,1.0,1.0,
        -0.1,-0.9,1.0,1.0,
        -0.1,-0.1,1.0,1.0,
        -0.9,-0.1,1.0,1.0,


        0.1,0.1,1.0,1.0,
        0.9,0.1,1.0,1.0,
        0.9,0.9,1.0,1.0,
        0.1,0.9,1.0,1.0,

        -0.9,0.1,1.0,1.0,
        -0.1,0.1,1.0,1.0,
        -0.1,0.9,1.0,1.0,
        -0.9,0.9,1.0,1.0,

        0.1,-0.1,1.0,1.0,
        0.1,-0.9,1.0,1.0,
        0.9,-0.9,1.0,1.0,
        0.9,-0.1,1.0,1.0
    };

GLuint indices_uint[]=
    {
          0,1,2,3,222,//Triangle 0 
          4,5,6,7,222,//Triangle 1
          8,9,10,11,222,//Triangle 2    
          12,13,14,15,222,//Triangle 3

          4,5,6,7,222,//Triangle 1
          8,9,10,11,222,//Triangle 2    
          4,5,6,7,222,//Triangle 1        
          12,13,14,15,222//Triangle 3
    };

glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);

glPrimitiveRestartIndex(222);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);

glVertexAttribPointer(position, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,vertices);

glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,7,10,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,indices_uint,4);
```

I am not sure what exactly the output should be.The code renders Triangle 1 and Triangle 2.
How exactly Triangle 2 is drawn when I am passing [start,end] as [0,7] ?

The spec says :

```
Index values lying outside the range [start, end] are treated in the same way as glDrawElementsBaseVertex()
```

Does it mean that even if {8,9,10,11} are outside [0,7] range they will still be used for rendering ? If so then why do we have to use glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex() ?

Comment: You don't *have* to use `glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex` at all. That's your choice. Personally, I'd say to avoid the Range functions entirely unless you're using client-side vertex arrays. Of course, then I'd say to stop using client-side vertex arrays.

Answer (score 1):

> The spec says :

And right before that line, the spec says:

> with the additional constraint that all values in the array indices​ must lie between start​ and end​, inclusive, **prior to adding basevertex​.**

The start and end indices are the indicies before adding the base vertex to them. The idea being that your start/end indices match what is in the index array, not the post-offset index values.

Also, the line you quoted is a typo; the actual specification says:

> Index values lying outside the range [start; end] are treated in the same way as **DrawRangeElements**.

The typo has been corrected on [the OpenGL Wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex).

Comment: Can you please throw some light on how exactly the basevertex affects the index values ?
My understanding is that basevertex is simply added to the supplied index array i.e. the position offset into index array.
So in above mentioned example , after I pass 4 as basevertex value triangle 1 and triangle 2 indices will be passed i.e. &indices_uint[5] to &indices_uint[14] data will be supplied. My question is if I am passing [0,7] range Triangle 2 should not be rendered since the indices {8,9,10,11} are outside the specified range. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @maverick9888: The range has *nothing* to do with what "is rendered". If an index falls outside of the range, you get "implementation-defined behavior". That includes, but is not limited to, "renders fine". Or "renders fine sometimes, but not others." And so forth.

Comment: @maverick9888: As for how the basevertex works, are you asking me to explain what "indices​[i] + basevertex" means?

Comment: Actually the "implementation-defined behavior" confused me. I am getting different results on different platforms when the index values are falling outside [start,end] range. Got that now. I know how basevertex works but I thought it might have some different significance in conjunction with glDrawRangeElementsBaseVertex ().

Comment: @maverick9888: The only difference that Range does is provide the specification of a *range*. Nothing more. And as I said in the answer, the range is for the indices *before* the base vertex addition, not after. So your drawing command has completely defined behavior, and it *should* draw those two triangles.

Comment: Drawing commands have a defined behavior but the indices supplied are affected by "implementation-defined behavior" in my case. So I cant guarantee that Triangle 1 and Triangle 2 will be rendered. Are you saying the output I am getting is Correct and Implementation Independent ? Please see the code again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23947/discussion-between-nicol-bolas-and-maverick9888)